# What is the error in my form email input . It always returns false while submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think the problem is in the jQuery. Whenever some value is entered in the Email input and try to submit the form It shows false weather the value is correct or not. Please help me. My whole code is down please go through it and please check the **jQUERY SECTION** thoroughly as I think the problem is not in HTML it is in the jQuery

Responses will be appreciated.

```js
 function isEmail(email) {

            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

                return regex.test(email);

            }
 $("#submit").click(function() {
 alert(isEmail($("#email").val()));
 });
```

```css
 body{

 font-family: Lato;
 font-size: 200%
 }
 input{

 height: 40px;
 padding: 5px 5px 12px 5px;
 font-size: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 width: 320px;
 }
 label{

 position: relative; 
 top: 5px;
 float: left;
 width: 275px;
 }
 #wrapper{

 width: 625px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .elements{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 #submit{
 width: 130px;
 margin-left: 275px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 height: 55px;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>jQuery</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="wrapper">

 <div class="elements">
 <label for="Email">Email</label>
 <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="eg:yourname@gmail.com">
 </div>
 <div class="elements">
 <label for="Phone">Phone No</label>
 <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone No" placeholder="eg:1234567890">
 </div> 
 <div class="elements">
 <label for="Password">Password</label>
 <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password">
 </div> 
 <div class="elements">
 <label for="confirmPassword">ConfirmPassword</label>
 <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword">
 </div>
 <div class="elements">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up">
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nitish, If you aware then javascript is case sensitive your tag ID= "Email" whereas your click contains small e.

So replace

```
alert(isEmail($("#email").val()))
```

with

```
alert(isEmail($("#Email").val()))
```

and everything works!!

Answer (score 0):

Your alert statement is incorrect. Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>jQuery</title>
 <style type="text/css">

 body{

 font-family: Lato;
 font-size: 200%
 }
 input{

 height: 40px;
 padding: 5px 5px 12px 5px;
 font-size: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 width: 320px;
 }
 label{

 position: relative; 
 top: 5px;
 float: left;
 width: 275px;
 }
 #wrapper{

 width: 625px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .elements{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 #submit{
 width: 130px;
 margin-left: 275px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 height: 55px;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="wrapper">

 <div class="elements">
 <label for="Email">Email</label>
 <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="eg:yourname@gmail.com">
 </div>
 <div class="elements">
 <label for="Phone">Phone No</label>
 <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone No" placeholder="eg:1234567890">
 </div> 
 <div class="elements">
 <label for="Password">Password</label>
 <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password">
 </div> 
 <div class="elements">
 <label for="confirmPassword">ConfirmPassword</label>
 <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword">
 </div>
 <div class="elements">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up">
 </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function isEmail(email) {

            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

                return regex.test(email);

            }
 $("#submit").click(function() 
 {
   alert($("#Email").val());
 });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery are case sensitive.
You have :

```
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="eg:yourname@gmail.com">
```

So you must use:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
 alert(isEmail($("#Email").val()));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have mismatched the id for email. try changinbg id from `#email` to `#Email` in the jQuery and it will work

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
console.log($("#Email").val());
 alert(isEmail($("#Email").val()));
 });
 
  function isEmail(email) {

           var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
           
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());

            }
```

```css
body{

 font-family: Lato;
 font-size: 200%
 }
 input{

 height: 40px;
 padding: 5px 5px 12px 5px;
 font-size: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 width: 320px;
 }
 label{

 position: relative; 
 top: 5px;
 float: left;
 width: 275px;
 }
 #wrapper{

 width: 625px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .elements{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 #submit{
 width: 130px;
 margin-left: 275px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 height: 55px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

 <div class="elements">
 <label for="Email">Email</label>
 <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="eg:yourname@gmail.com">
 </div>
 
 <div class="elements">
 <label for="Phone">Phone No</label>
 <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone No" placeholder="eg:1234567890">
 </div> 
 
 <div class="elements">
 <label for="Password">Password</label>
 <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password">
 </div> 
 
 <div class="elements">
 <label for="confirmPassword">ConfirmPassword</label>
 <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword">
 </div>
 
 <div class="elements">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up">
 </div>
 
 </div>
```